# Android extended toolbar material design guidelines

Tags: design-patterns, material-design, android-toolbar

I studied the Material design guidelines but I could not find any specific info for the heights of the extended toolbar.

I'm working on a custom view that takes up two rows of the action bar and comes to a total of 92dp in height. There is a Floating Action Button anchored at the start|left position.

Now, I'm curious to find out if the extended tool bar is supposed to have prefixed heights (determined by the design guidelines) or do the guidelines allow developers to customize the height to our own views?

I know that I can technically create a toolbar of any length, but I wanted to find out from a material design guidelines perspective! They talk about the metrics [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar). But, I don't see anything concrete!

Comment: In smartphone it should be 56+72dp if portrait and 48dp+72dp if Landscape.
In the tablet it should be 64+64

Comment: Okay. Also, is there a restriction on the content that can be placed in that 72dp space?